# Reading live logs via SSH

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

I am in the early stages of a log reading app in Cocoa / Objective-C and I am having trouble finding the most efficient method of doing this. The logs are "live" and only available via SSH to a remote host. The data will be parsed in my app. (This is a Mac OSX app, not iOS using XCode 4.0 on SL)

So far I found 2 methods:

1. Use NSTask to execute ssh and 'file-tail -f -n0'  in conjunction
   with NSPipe.
2. Include File-tail itself in my app (Available on Apple's opensource page) and go from there.

If it was just HTML or XML I needed to grab I would be fine, but the need for ssh and file-tailing of a "Live" log are making this hard to figure out.

Any suggestions? Is there something similar to "file-tail" hidden in a framework somewhere I am missing?
Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File tail isn't really your problem - you can simulate it with something like a dispatch_source.   The hard thing to write yourself is the ssh client.  There are some open source clients but as far as I know none are really structured to be a liberey.  Also some have problematic licences.

Using NStask is likely to be either one open source liberey and 75 lines less glue code, or about 3k less lines of code (sorry total guesswork, I've never written a ssh v2 client, only v1).

NStask is normally more brittle then having built in code, but with ssh the main source of brittleness is likely the network+remote configuration+local config.  NStask will be lost in the noise.

I would favor use of NStask here.

Comment: NSTask worked quite well and I now have SSH hitting a NSTextView window. Thanks for the advice!